# Rome airport - How to get from Terminal 1 to Terminal 5?

Tags: transit, fco

How to get from terminal 1 to terminal 5 at Rome airport?

Where I can get my boarding pass?

I have 3:25h between flights; is that okay?

Comment: Why are you shouting? And why did you select the Minneapolis tag?

Comment: My flight is from Rome to Minneapolis.

Comment: Yes, I do not know where I can get my boarding pass, sometimes you cannot find machine so easy.

Comment: Since Fiumicino is the only Rome airport with five terminals, seems like a genuine duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

You have enough time.

According to the FCO web site says there is a free shuttle between terminal 5 and the other terminals:

[...]How do I reach the terminals?
A free shuttle bus service operates all year, connecting the airport, the car parks and the Cargo City approximately every 15 minutes (from 1 am to 4 am only if called from the intercoms installed at the stops).

**For Terminal 5 a free shuttle bus service is available with stops at the Departures level**.
[...]

from http://www.adr.it/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en-/pax-fco-faq

Comment: My flight is just a connecting flight. I will come from Belgrade on Terminal 1 and after I have flight from Terminal 5. I am in transit just....

Comment: Usually you get your boarding passes for from the point of departure (Belgrade); both from the Belgrade to Rome and Rome to Minneapolis; if unsure, ask when getting your first boarding pass and/or when landing in Rome.